# Проблема с анимацией в Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация, разработка-игр

**Прилагаю скриншот проблемы.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думаю что проблема в том, что я склеил коды двух разных авторов, и с чем-то прогадал при редактировании.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerPlatformerController : PhysicsObject {

public float maxSpeed = 5;
public float jumpTakeOffSpeed = 8;
public AnimationClip walkAnimation;
public AnimationClip runAnimation;
public float walkAnimationSpeed;
public float runAnimationSpeed;
private bool isWalk;
private bool isRun;
private Animation _animation;

private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

void Start () {
    _animation = GetComponent<Animation>();
    _animation[walkAnimation.Walk].speed = walkAnimationSpeed;
    _animation[runAnimation.Run].speed = runAnimationSpeed;
   
    }

void Awake () 
{
    spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();    
}

void Update () {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.W)){
    isWalk = true; 
    maxSpeed = 5;
            }
            if(Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.W)){
    isWalk = false;
            }
            if(Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.LeftShift)){
    isRun = true;  
            }
            if(Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.LeftShift)){
    isRun = false; 
            }
            if(isWalk && !isRun){
            _animation.CrossFade (walkAnimation.Walk);     
            }
            if(isWalk && isRun){
            _animation.CrossFade (runAnimation.Run);
            maxSpeed = 8;    
            }
            if(!isWalk){
            _animation.Stop(walkAnimation.Walk);
            _animation.Stop(runAnimation.Run);
            }
}

protected override void ComputeVelocity()
{
    Vector2 move = Vector2.zero;

    move.x = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");

    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump") && grounded) {
        velocity.y = jumpTakeOffSpeed;
    } else if (Input.GetButtonUp ("Jump")) 
    {
        if (velocity.y > 0) {
            velocity.y = velocity.y * 0.5f;
        }
    }

    bool flipSprite = (spriteRenderer.flipX ? (move.x > 0.01f) : (move.x < 0.01f));
    if (flipSprite) 
    {
        spriteRenderer.flipX = !spriteRenderer.flipX;
    }
    targetVelocity = move * maxSpeed;
}
}
```

Comment: наверное проблема в том, что написано в ошибке. Пробовал закинуть текст ошибки в переводчик?

Comment: Я знаю что там написано, я просто не знаю, как это исправить.

Comment: `error CS0000: 'Autor' does not contain a definition for 'Think' and no accessible extension method 'LearnTo'`

Comment: Очень смешно, я думал мне тут помогут...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, если вы этого еще не сделали, то в инспекторе закиньте в переменные

```
public AnimationClip walkAnimation;
public AnimationClip runAnimation;
```

Клипы под названием `Walk` и `Run`.

Во-вторых, в методе `Start()` у вас первая ошибка:

```
_animation[walkAnimation.Walk].speed = walkAnimationSpeed;
_animation[runAnimation.Run].speed = runAnimationSpeed;
```

Здесь вы пытаетесь обратиться к переменной типа `AnimationClip` так, как будто у нее есть методы `Walk` и `Run`. Вместо этого вам нужно внимательнее посмотреть на тип, которых требуется указать в квадратный скобках (подсказка, это тип `string`), поэтому нужно переписать метод `Start()`:

```
void Start () 
{
    _animation = GetComponent<Animation>();
    _animation[walkAnimation.name].speed = walkAnimationSpeed;
    _animation[runAnimation.name].speed = runAnimationSpeed;   
}
```

Далее, вам нужно исправить эту же ошибку в методе `Update()` и вообще везде, где вы используете `_animation.CrossFade()` или `_animation.Stop()` вам точно также в круглых скобках нужно поставить `walkAnimation.name` или `runAnimation.name` (в зависимости от требуемого), так как оба этих метода тоже принимают в качестве параметра тип string.